# Why does ActiveRecord return fields encoded as ASCII-8BIT even with mysql2 gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, character-encoding, ruby-1.9

I have been getting this error in Ruby 1.9, Rails 3.0, ActiveRecord 3.0:

```
incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)
```

This is happening because the string on which I'm trying to call `gsub` (which comes directly from an ActiveRecord object field) has an encoding of `ASCII-8BIT`.  I've read several articles, posts and answers saying that this is caused by the mysql gem encoding things wrong, and suggesting mysql2.

But I am using mysql2 already.  I've tried a 0.2.x version and the latest 0.3.7 version and neither solve the problem:

```
irb> str = Discussion.first.content
=> "Something's wrong with encodings..." 
irb> str.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

I've changed the database encoding and the table encoding in MySQL, I've also tried setting the LANG env variable with no luck.  Is there anywhere else I can look or to see why I'm getting this wrong encoding?

Comment: Here's another bit of info: \_\_ENCODING\_\_, Encoding.default_external and Encoding.default_internal all return UTF-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha!  My shallowness of knowledge strikes again.  The problem was indeed in database.yml:

```
development:
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: mysql2
  [...]
```

I was still using `adapter: mysql` so even though the `mysql2` gem was installed it wasn't being *used*.  I didn't realize I'd have to change the name of it in `database.yml`; I thought it would *replace* the old `mysql` gem.

Now we all know! :)

Comment: Note: This does NOT work in DataMapper projects!  I don't know why the adapter is apparently called mysql2 in ActiveRecord (?), but in DataMapper projects, using `mysql2` in database.yml will just cause an error, because the name of the adapter DM uses is `mysql`.  DataMapper uses the do-mysql driver, which doesn't have character-encoding problems, and so the mysql2 gem is unnecessary.  And wouldn't help anyway, since dm-mysql-adapter doesn't utilize it.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.1.71 with Rails 4.0.2 running on Ruby 2.0.0-p353.

In database.yml, encoding is set to "utf8" and adapter is "mysql2" for all environments.

My tables are all using UTF-8, "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci".

Any ideas on where else I can look to see why ActiveRecord hands me ASCII-8BIT strings?

Comment: Asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719767/activerecord-in-rails-4-0-4-gives-ascii-8bit-with-mysql2-encoding-set-to-utf8

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the connection encoding correctly in `config/database.yml`?

```
development:
  encoding: utf8
```

Comment: I wasn't!  But I added that to my database.yml file and it didn't change anything.  Shoot.  Thanks for the tip though!